# How to change font_name property for lables in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, label

I'm trying to create a label, specify some text for it and use some custom font, using the property "font_name" in the python file, not in kv file. here is the code:

python code:

```
some_text = bidi.algorithm.get_display(
        arabic_reshaper.reshape(<some_persian_text>))


MDLabel(text=some_text, size_hint=(None, None), font_name="fonts/Shabnam-Bold", size=(300, 100), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .8}))
```

corresponding kv file:

```
<SomeScreen>:
    name: 'some_screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        id: main_layout
        size: self.width, self.height
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        MDToolbar:
            id: main_toolbar
            title: "TITLE"
            # left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: side_bar.set_state('open')]]
            left_action_items:[['arrow-left', lambda x: root.go_back()]]
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            elevation: 15
```

As you can see, I have set the Toolbar in the kv file and I'm trying to render some other content for it dynamically in python. The text of the label is in Persian(some right-to-left language spoken in Iran).The bidi library alongside arabic_reshaper enable the app to render right-to-left text. The problem is, when I do this totally in kv file (setting the text in python, creating the label in kv file and setting the text and font_name also in kv file), everything works fine. But when I do it in this way(creating and setting the label content and the font in py file), the font does not work properly and shows some nonsense:

[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem can be solved using markup tags:

```
'[font = "path/to/font"]your text [/font]'
```